# How to get member name when member leaves server after bot restarts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The code given below works fine when:

1. I start bot
2. User joins server => I get username
3. User leaves server => I get username of member who left

But when I have such sequence:

1. I start bot
2. User joins server => I get username
3. **I restart bot: turn it off and then on**
4. User leaves server => **I didn't get username**

I have DB with usernames, so after user leaves I need to delete him from DB. Bot restarts when I for example deploy updated bot version. Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    username = member.name
    await member.send('Hello')
    print(username)


@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    username = member.name
    print(username)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I'm using discord.py 1.5.0. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I copied your code my test bot and have not been able to reproduce your problem. The only thing I can think of is maybe your bot is not "ready" by the time your member leaves? try adding a `on_ready` event so you know your bot is loaded. Testing on my bot I turned it off and on several times and it would always give me the username

Comment: @AbdurJ I'm using `on_ready`, and I have a message when It's ready, but I still have same problem: when member leaves server after bot restarts I don't have a message with member name.

Comment: I've tried several times now, and I just can't seem to reproduce your problem. Short video of the test I did: [link](https://streamable.com/jo6xvr)

Comment: @AbdurJ thank you for your video! That's very strange for me. I will try to run my code on another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this code doesn't work in my case:

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

But I tried to declare intents as @AbdurJ in his video:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

And it works!